# resolution of vii 7th chord 3rd inversion

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, chord-inversions

[image]

The image above (from Korean composer Byung Dong Paik's Theory of Harmonics, page 130) shows progressions diminished and half-diminished 7th chords 3rd inversion

But there seems to be another solution, but no more examples and explanations.

the progression at the bottom of the image, perfect 4th is come out in succession., but can I change the progression to A-D-F-B(vii24) -> G-E-G-C(I64) -> G-D-G-B(V) ?

or

can I change the progression to A-D-F-B(vii24) -> G-D-G-B(V) -> C-E-G-C(I) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the two progressions is that in the vii chords, the F (the chordal seventh) is expected to resolve down by step to E or Eb.

So the two progressions are "allowable", but awkward.

Comment: the F (the chordal seventh) is expected to resolve down by step to E or Eb. <--you mean, are you talking about examples of images? And the fact that the process I made is awkward means that the example of an image is the most appropriate?

Comment: @guss2222 Correct. In your progressions, the F proceeds upwards to G; in the book's examples, the F moves downward, which is more typical. The upward movement is not forbidden, however.

Comment: i understand thank you. and It sounds silly, but my questions almost always seem to be answered by you.

Comment: @guss2222 It seems we're often online around the same time.